# Previewing MSWord (.doc and .docx) files in Horde Webmail

Tags: email, mime, preview, horde

While making changes in Horde's mime_drivers.php file to allow inline HTML in emails, I noticed a setting that allows MS Word documents to be opened in an appropriate program:

```
/* MS Word display.
 * This driver requires AbiWord to be installed.
 * AbiWord homepage: http://www.abisource.com/ */
'msword' => array(
    // Disabled by default
    'disable' => true,
    'handles' => array(
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.ms-word'
    ),
    'icons' => array(
        'default' => 'msword.png'
    ),

    // REQUIRED: Location of the AbiWord binary
    'location' => '/usr/bin/abiword'
),
```

In our previous email program, our text documents, including MSWord, could be previewed within the browser without downloading. There was [a thread in Horde's mailing list regarding a similar setup](http://lists.horde.org/archives/imp/Week-of-Mon-20120625/thread.html), but the asker had a higher technical knowledge than me and seems to already have most of the pieces in place.

I'm a webmaster that only recently had to delve beyond cPanel and discover there's a whole new world keeping this website up and running! My best guess is that I need to find a program that can run on the server and convert .docx/other files to something presentable in HTML (the "abiword" referenced above, maybe?) and make the correct reference to said program in the mime_drivers.php file.

Comment: Abiword is an open-source word processor, sort of like LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Yes, I read up on it. There is a command line interface for it as well, apparently for converting documents.